# Appending html button and then calling its onClick event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append some html in a div i.e.

```
 $("#color").append('<label>Color</label><select id="sel"><option>Natural</option><option>Black</option><option>White</option><option>Navy</option></select></br><label>Quantity</label> </span><input type="text" name="qty"></br><label>Unit Price</label><div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on">$</span><input type="text" name="uprice"><span class="add-on">.00</span></div></br>**<a href="#" id="item-add" class="btn btn-info">Add Item</a>**');
```

and then trying to call that button Click function i.e.

```
$('#item-add').on('click','.(function(){

        alert("HELLO");
});
```

But it doesn't seems to be working. Please help. Thanks

Comment: First of all you have syntax error in your code, clear the "'.(" characters before the function keyword. Second, it's not quite clear what you mean by "call an event", but you can manually invoke (trigger) an event on an object with the trigger function, like $('#item-add').trigger('click')

Answer (score 2):

Replace your event handler like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#item-add', function() {
    alert("HELLO");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look syntax error, could you try that;

```
$('#item-add').on('click',function(){

        alert("HELLO");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong code in the question. But making a function and using the attribute onClick made it happen. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try your click event like this

```
$('#item-add').on('click',(function(){
        alert("HELLO");
});
```